# iOS: Table view, allow scrolling "further down" than the end

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

Sorry the question sounds a bit confusing. I have two buttons overlapping my table view at the bottom, so if the table view scrolls "normal" the last row is partially hidden by these buttons. That's why I want to allow scrolling the table like the height of one row further down, so the last row is on top of these two buttons. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe enlarge contentSize height would work.

Comment: Can you simply make the table view a little shorter so that the buttons are shown below it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adjust the content insets of the table view.

For instance, if your buttons are 50 points in height and your table's frame is the full window, you could set your table to snap to the top of your buttons like this:

`tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 50, 0);`

Note: In iOS 7+ view controllers have a property `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` that is set to `YES` by default.  When this property is set to `YES`, the contentInsets you set manually may be overridden.  Assuming you have a nav bar of some kind that you want to scroll under, you can set your top edge inset to the length of the topLayoutGuide.

**Your final solution** (put this in viewDidLoad):

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, 50, 0);
```

Comment: Glad I could help! p.s. this trick is actually relevant to ALL scroll views (e.g. table view, collection view, web view, scroll view, etc etc.)

Comment: Good explanation & easy answer :)
Upvote for question & answer.

Comment: Deprecated in 2018.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin

Comment: @ScottyBlades what's the replacement?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by others, deprecations have made this solution impossible, and if we use a section footer, this will display at the inset all the time. A much simpler solution would be to add a tableFooterView to allow the bottom cells to scroll past the buttons. Like so:

```
    let bottomView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 83))
    bottomView.backgroundColor = .clear
    tableView.tableFooterView = bottomView
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make it so the contents shift up.
If you want them to shift down you can change the insets accordingly.

```
    func shiftScrollingUp() {
        yourScrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        yourScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 150, 0)
    }
```

`AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` [is deprecated in ios 11.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin)